# function works on one element of list, doesn't work on full list, R

Tags: r, list, function, user-defined-functions, lapply

I'm trying to make a function to add tags to a data frame.
The name of the data frame contains the information I need (date, selection, treatment, etc...). So I made a function that extracts the information I need. I have a large list containing all the data frames, and when I apply the function to the list, it does create the new columns for the tags but the values are NA-s. Every data frame has the same name structure, and if I extract a data frame from the list and run the function it works. Can you help me find out why doesn't it work when I apply it to the list?

here is my function :

```
library(stringr)

tagging <- function(H){

  namey<-deparse(substitute(H)) #get the name of the data frame 
  namey<- str_sub(namey,1, -5) #drop the .csv 
  H$date<-substring(namey,1, 6) # get the first 6 characters containing the date 
  H$selection<- word(namey, -1) #get the last word 
  H$treatment<- word(namey, -2) # get the second last word
  H$REP<- word(namey, -3) # get the third last word 
  return(H)
  }
```

And I apply it like this

```
 ListofData.tagged<-lapply(ListofData, tagging)
```

The name of the data frames looks like this:

```
180503 xyz1-6 R4_A6_xyz 5 yes.csv
```

Comment: Could you prove a minimal example of what `ListofData` contains?

Comment: Looks like it is the file name instead of the object name. I think you need to loop through the names of the `ListofData`?

Comment: Try `map(names(ListofDatalst), ~ str_sub(.x, 1, -5))`

Comment: The problem is a `lapply` problem: it passes `X[[1]]`, then `X[[2]]`, etc to the function. Put `cat("namey:", namey, "\n")` right after `deparse/substitute` to see what is the df name in the function.

Comment: Anders Ellern Bilgrau : ListofData contains 300 data frames. Each dataframe has the same structure, same variables and the same "structure" for the name. 
 akrun : the name of the file is the name of the object, because I import the .csv files as follows :
      temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
      ListofData = lapply(temp, read.csv)

Comment: @RuiBarradas You are right! indeed the function gives namey:X[[i]]... Do you have a suggestion how to get the names that I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import this way so you keep your names:

```
library(tidyverse)
ListofData <- map(set_names(temp), read_csv)
```

then we modify your function to add the name as a second parameter, which will be used through `imap`, so we get rid of the first line too :

```
tagging <- function(H, namey){
  namey<- str_sub(namey,1, -5) #drop the .csv 
  H$date<-substring(namey,1, 6) # get the first 6 characters containing the date 
  H$selection<- word(namey, -1) #get the last word 
  H$treatment<- word(namey, -2) # get the second last word
  H$REP<- word(namey, -3) # get the third last word 
  return(H)
  }
```

Then `imap` passes the data to the `H` argument and the element names to the `namey` argument.

```
ListofData.tagged <- imap(ListofData, tagging)
```

---

base R translation

```
ListofData <- lapply(setNames(temp,temp), read.csv)
ListofData.tagged <- Map(tagging, ListofData, names(ListofData))
```

---

Or if you don't care about naming the elements of `ListofData` you can do directly `Map(tagging, ListofData, temp)` (still keeping the new definition of `tagging`).